# getting an element in JavaScript

Tags: c#, javascript

i have the following html code:

```
<select name="drop1" id="Select1" size="4" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="1">item 1</option>
    <option value="2">item 2</option>
    <option value="3">item 3</option>
    <option value="4">item 4</option>
    <option value="0">All</option>
</select>
```

this code is available in a user control, so its id changes when i run the web application.
how can i get the selected items from JavaScript on a button click?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=clientid+javascript

Answer (score 2):

If you are using ASP.NET 4 you could set static ids in web.config:

```
<system.web>
    <pages clientIDMode="Static"></pages>
</system.web>
```

this way you know the generated ID.

If you are not using ASP.NET 4.0 an alternative is to declare a global js variable:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // TODO: be careful here and make sure the DOM is loaded
    var mySelect = document.getElementById('<%= Select1.ClientID %>');
</script>
```

which could be used later to manipulate the select.

Comment: to make sue that the Dom is loaded i can use jquery $(document).ready() right? and i have to use your code inside my usercontrol where the select is located? will this also work if the select was inside a div?

Comment: Oh, you are using jquery? You should have stated this in your question. Yes you should use `$(document).ready` but with jquery you could also use CSS selectors. For example give your DropDownList a CSS class and then: `var selectedValue = $('.myddl').val();`. You don't need to bother with mangled ids.

Comment: As an addition to DOM load if you put your script at the end of the page just before the closing body you no longer need to wrap your code in a `$(document).ready` statement because at that moment it will already be loaded.

Answer (score 0):

In plain JavaScript:

```
var value = document.getElementById('Select1').value;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can't use .NET 4.0 to control IDs and you don't want to add extra markup to the page, you need to retrieve the control's element using the Client ID:

```
var ddl = document.getElementByID('<%= Select1.ClientID %>');
```

Edit: If you are using jquery, you can do this if you don't want to add an extra class to your DropDownList:

```
var value = $('#<%= Select1.ClientID %>').val();
```

Answer (score 0):

With jquery:

$("select[name= drop1]").val()